# Call and temporarily store and object within an MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am still in the process of learning the ASP.NET MVC3 Razor engine, and I'm trying to wrap my head around how to accomplish something that seems so **incredibly simple**.

I have a static class that encapsulates a method which calls a third party API.  My `_Layout.cshtml` *master page* calls the static class, e.g.

```
if(@Rf.Models.PageContent.GetSomething().IsSomethingHappening) {
   <span>@Rf.Models.PageContent.GetSomething().Name</span>
}
```

As you can see I am duplicating effort (and a call to the third party API) from my static class PageContent, method GetSomething -- which returns a class.

In regular old MVC2, I would have done something like this:

```
<% var obj = Rf.Models.PageContent.GetSomething();
   if(obj.IsSomethingHappening) { %>
   <span><%=obj.Name%></span>
<% } %>
```

...which doesn't duplicate effort.

I want to call PageContent.GetSomething() once, store it, and reference it if my flag is true.  I do not want to call PageContent.GetSomething() again, if my flag is true.

This may be a very simple question, but I'm a bit stuck on how to accomplish it.  How can I duplicate the same kind of functionality from within the Razor engine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equivalent in Razor would be:

```
@{
    var obj = Rf.Models.PageContent.GetSomething();
}

@if (obj.IsSomethingHappening)
{
    <span>@obj.Name</span>
}
```

Obviously having views to pull data from static methods is one of the ugliest and anti-MVC practice. Views shouldn't pull any data. They should only use data that was provided to them by the controller.

So here's the correct way to do this:

```
public class FooController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var obj = Rf.Models.PageContent.GetSomething();
        return PartialView(obj);
    }
}
```

and in the corresponding view (`~/Views/Foo/Index.cshtml`):

```
@model AppName.Models.SomeViewModel
@if (Model.IsSomethingHappening)
{
    <span>@Model.Name</span>
}
```

and to call this from your `_Layout` simply:

```
@Html.Action("Index", "Foo")
```

Comment: Awesome, your advice is golden. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use the @{} syntax

```
@{
    var obj = Rf.Models.PageContent.GetSomething();    
 }

 @if (obj.IsSomethingHappening)
 {
     <span><@obj.Name></span>
 }
```